# Does HERE isoline API account for time waiting at intersections?

Tags: routes, here-api

I am testing out HERE's [calculate isoline API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html) and want to know a little more about how the time taken along routes is calculated.

In particular, does the API account for time taken waiting at intersections, or does it just apply some historical average speed to each link along the route?

Answer (score 0):

For the estimation of traffic times, there is no difference between enabled and disabled traffic modes. Historical, real time and predictive traffic are taken into account based on the specified arrival/departure times.

See documentation on traffic mode type:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html#type-traffic-mode